# How to make variable that can be used in many views?

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-view

I have a project, it has a structure like this:

http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/2333/92348689.png

I want to make a variable like the following

```
$templatePath = $this->baseUrl('/application/templates/')`
```

and it can be used in many views, in many modules. I think I can do it by declaring the variable in `Bootstrap.php` (application) but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Look at Zend_Registry

Comment: Can I make it in bootstrap file?

Comment: @zavg I added other image link.

Comment: Yep ... you can make it in the bootstrap.

Comment: to set `Zend_Registry::set("MyVar", "MyVal");`  to get `Zend_Registry::get("MyVar"); // returns MyVal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, I just place myself such variables into application bootstrap file. Here's an example:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initViewVariables() {
        $this->bootstrap('View');

        $this->view->fooValue = 'foo';
        $this->view->barValue = 'bar';

        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

        if( $config->recaptcha->enabled ) {
            $this->view->captcha = true;
            $this->view->recaptchaPublicKey = $config->recaptcha->publicKey;
        }
        else {
            $this->view->captcha = false;
        }

    }

}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Base Url is  available after routing has been completed (routeShutdown hook) so accessing it in Bootstrap will not work .

So create a controller plugin inside preDispatch() do

```
public function preDispatch($req) {

$view = new Zend_View();
$view->placeholder('burl')->set(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl());

}
```

To access it inside view do  like index.phtml

```
 echo $this->placeholder('burl');
```

Comment: Hi, it works. But I want it can work in any controller, it means that it can work in any view (I have three modules). I don't want type or copy many times this method in other controller. What should I do?

Comment: @StuartRedman you should then use define('BASE_URL',Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl());

Comment: I'm sorry but where I can put define(...)? And Can I pass a string into getBaseUrl()? Ex: Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl('abc'));

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Zend_Registry.

In your bootstrap or wherever in your site just State

```
 Zend_Registry::set("TagLine", "Have a Nice Day");
```

To use in a view just

```
 <?= Zend_Registry::get("TagLine"); ?>
```

for extra credit you could also make a view helper for this (there is one with ZF2)

```
class My_View_Helper_Registry extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function registry($key)
    {
        return Zend_Registry::get($key);
    }
}
```

In your bootstrap you will add a method like:

```
protected function _initSiteRegistry(){
    Zend_Registry::set("Site_Name", "My Cool Site";
    Zend_Registry::set("Site_TagLine", "Have a nice day";
}
```

Also if you are using the view helper approach you will also want to register the helper path.. you can do this in _initView in the bootstrap.

```
    protected function _initView(){
            $view = new Zend_View();
            $view->doctype("HTML5");
            $view->setEncoding("UTF-8");
            $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/local/views");
            // set this as the viewRenderer's view. 
            $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
            $view->addHelperPath("My/View/Helper/", "My_View_Helper_");
            return $view;
    }
```

Comment: How I do it in Bootstrap file? in public function _init(){} or something function ...

Comment: You could just create a new protected method in the bootstrap called something like `_initSiteVariables` or something. I will update the answer to show an example

Comment: I got an error if I try use $this->baseUrl in _initSiteRegistry(), have no problem with string value => Zend_Registry::set("templatePath", $this->baseUrl("/application/templates/"));

Comment: baseUrl is a viewHelper you have to be on a view to use it. You can get a servicable view by saying `$this->bootstrap('view'); $view = $this->getResource('view'); $view->baseUrl("/application/templates/");`

Comment: Thanks but I still got an error Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "view" not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zendfirst\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php

Comment: protected function _initSiteRegistry() {
   // baseUrl is a viewHelper
   $this->bootstrap("view");
   $view = $this->getResource("view");
   Zend_Registry::set("templatePath", $view->baseUrl("/application/templates/"));
  }